# Como hago para que el programa detecte datos duplicados dentro de una matriz en java

Tags: java, matrices, matriz

Basicamente lo que quiero hacer es, dentro de java, que el programa vaya comparando con una variable una matriz con todos los nombres ya existentes, y de ahi detecte si hay dos o varios nombres repetidos y me lo cuente.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [][] nombres = new String [1][6];
    String repetido="";
    int contador = 1;
    
    nombres[0][0]="Juan";
    nombres[0][1]="Aurelia";
    nombres[0][2]="Martin";
    nombres[0][3]="Mauro";
    nombres[0][4]="Juan";
    nombres[0][5]="Martin";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < 6; l++) {
                    repetido = nombres [k][l];
                    if (repetido.equals(nombres[k][l])){
                        System.out.println("{"+k+"] "+"{"+l+"}");
                        contador++;
                    }else{
                        return; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(contador);
}
```

}

Comment: "comparando con una variable una matriz", que variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas un array bidimensional para almacenar una lista de nombres, por lo demás, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías comparar los nombres de un array, si quieres hacerlo bidimensional solo tienes que adaptarlo como veas oportuno.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] nombres = new String[6];
        int contador = 0; //Inicializamos contador a 0

        nombres[0]="Juan";
        nombres[1]="Aurelia";
        nombres[2]="Martin";
        nombres[3]="Mauro";
        nombres[4]="Juan";
        nombres[5]="Martin";

        for(int i=0;i<nombres.length;i++){//Primer bucle para recorrer el array nombre por nombre
            if(nombres[i].equals(""))//Si el nombre ha sido eliminado, continua sin entrar al bucle de j
                continue;
            for(int j=0;j<nombres.length;j++){//Segundo bucle para comparar cada nombre con todos los demás
                if(j != i && nombres[i].equals(nombres[j])){/*Si i es igual a j, está 
                comparando el mismo nombre, eso sería un falso positivo así que lo evito*/
                    nombres[j] = "";//Borro el nombre para evitar compararlo de nuevo
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(contador);
    }
```

Te dejo aclaraciones en los comentarios

Comment: Muchas gracias, justamente necesitaba un poco de empujon como ayuda. que tenga un buen dia

Comment: Si te sirvió, recuerda marcar como respuesta, así podrá servir a más gente @NjaJd !

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando como base lo propuesto por [@Benito-B](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/188830/benito-b), utilize solo un arreglo de (`String[]`) en lugar de un array (`String[][]`).

Lo que te propongo es que crees un Diccionario (Aquí la implementación de la clase `Dictionary` es [`HashTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)) con ese arreglo, que pongas como llave el nombre de las personas, y como el valor que posee esa llave el número de repeticiones del nombre. Así podrás en una sola iteración imprimir los nombres repetidos.

Enseguida te muestro el código que elabore:

```java
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> nombres = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Juan","Aurelia","Martin","Mauro","Juan","Martin","Martin"});
    Hashtable<String,Integer> diccionario = new Hashtable<>();
    for(String nombre: nombres) {
      if(diccionario.containsKey(nombre)){
        diccionario.put(nombre,diccionario.get(nombre).intValue() + 1);
      } else {
        diccionario.put(nombre,1);
      }
    }
    for(Enumeration<String> claves = diccionario.keys(); claves.hasMoreElements();) {
      String nombreActual = claves.nextElement();
      int repetido = diccionario.get(nombreActual);
      if(repetido > 1){
        System.out.printf("El nombre %s esta repetido %d veces.\n", nombreActual, repetido);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, pero no me convence el List, igual lo tomare para algo futuro.